# Help me Understand Hydronic System Boiler Circulator RPM / HP / Head / Flow / System Pressure

Tags: hvac, boiler, radiator, hydronic

Help me understand the correlation between boiler circulator RPM / HP / Head / Flow / System Pressure - see the particulars at the bottom.

CASE: My 1986 boiler came with Armstrong S25 circ (same as B&G 100). When the circ failed I replaced it in an emergency with the Taco 007. Now each time thermostat called for heat and the boiler kicked in I would hear 3-4 gentle pops from the boiler (within first 15 seconds, and never at other times). Someone here suggested lower head on the TACO 007 maybe the reason (24 vs 32). So I replaced the 007 with TACO 0010 (closest match to Armstrong S25). Sure enough the popping sounds are gone. But now water flow sound in pipes and rads is loud, and when the boiler heats up I am hearing a wailing sound. I can live with the water flow sound, but the wailing can be annoying. **Why is the TACO 0010 causing the wailing?** What part of the system can I adjust to stop it?

Cold system pressure has always been, and is now set at 12 PSI. When the boiler runs hot pressure rises to about 18 PSI.

PARTICULARS:

Cold system pressure: 12 / Height from gauge to the highest rad: 14 feet

Expansion tank: 12 PSI

Armstrong S25: 1750RPM; 1/12HP; 9-32 Flow-GPM (original system circ, was ideal setup)

TACO 007: 3250RPM; 1/25HP; 10-24 Flow-GPM (problem: few pops after boiler startup)

TACO 0010: 3250RPM; 1/8HP; 10-33 Flow-GPM (problem: water flow sound + wailing when boiler heats up)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the actual question, or do you want us to do your homework?

Comment: **Why is the TACO 0010 causing the wailing?** What part of the system can I adjust to stop it?

Comment: Just a WAG, but sounds like your flow rate is too high.

Comment: @SteveSh what is WAG ?

Comment: WAG: Wild-Ass Guess. Speculation without enough evidence to support it but which might be worth checking.

Comment: What keshlam said.  A somewhat better guess would be a SWAG - Scientific Wild Ass Guess.

Comment: Where is the expansion tank located relative to the pump intake/output? I expect you are hearing cavitation, which is *not good.* Frequently the expansion tank is in the wrong place relative to the pump, which aggravates this. Unless you have a particularly low set safety valve, might try increasing system pressure from 12 cold to 15-20 cold, which *might* be enough to stop that, while not tripping a typical 30 PSI pressure relief safety valve when hot. put **sound of pump cavitation** into a search engine for examples.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Definitely NOT cavitation sound. I hesitate raising pressure to test Ecnerwal's suggestion since it is already more than my home needs, by my calculation it should be good with about <10 PSI. I suspect the 0010 is too much of a circ for the system, despite roughly similar flow/head to Armstrong S25 (or B&G 100). But which specs are responsible? Velocity / horsepower?

Comment: I've gone back to 007 (prefer the few gentle pops when boiler come on to 0010's louder water flow and the moderate wailing). The 007 has lower flow than my original armstrong s25 (24 vs 32). **Is the lower flow somehow detrimental to the boiler?**

Answer (score 0):

The Taco 0010 is not the closest match for the Armstrong S25. The S25 is 8 foot head at no flow and 32GPM free delivery. Those match up with a Taco 008 circulator.

The Taco 0010 is 14’ shutoff head and 56 GPM free delivery. It’s pushing much more water through the pipes, which as you noticed can be noisy.

That said, I suspect you’re hearing air gurgle around because you need to purge the air from the system.

Comment: Entry 10 in the legend is for the Taco 0012. It has 52 GPM free flow.

Comment: @OliverStreet You're misreading the chart. Line 8 is the 0010 and has 10 foot shutoff and 33GPM open. The 009 has 35 feet shutoff and 10 GPM open, shown by line 7

Comment: @Ecnerwal - you’re quite right. The “wailing” that only shows up hot is must be system piping very sensitive to mass flow. He could find it if he could put his finger on it… literally. If it was cavitation he should have seen impressive impeller damage when the 0010 was swapped out for the 007 a month after my answer in December 2022, or maybe he didn’t look. By now the heat transfer has either been judged adequate or poor flow left some rooms cool as the burner short cycled in cold weather.